# How to access POST parameters in HttpServletRequest?

Tags: java, http, jersey, jetty

I've got an app that's basically a proxy to a service. The app itself is built on Jersey and served by Jetty. I have this Resource method:

```
@POST
@Path("/{default: .*}")
@Timed
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public MyView post(@Context UriInfo uriInfo, @Context HttpServletRequest request) {
  ...
}
```

A user submits a POST form. All POST requests go through this method. The UriInfo and HttpServletRequest are injected appropriately except for one detail: there seem to be no parameters. Here is my request being sent from the terminal:

```
POST /some/endpoint HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 15
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8
Host: localhost:8010
User-Agent: HTTPie/0.9.2

foo=bar&biz=baz
```

Here the POST body clearly contains 2 parameters: foo and biz. But when I try to get them in my code (`request.getParameterMap`) the result is a map of size 0.

How do I access these parameters or this parameter string from inside my resource method? If it matters, the implementation of `HttpServletRequest` that is used is org.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Three options

1. `@FormParam("<param-name>")` to gt individual params. Ex.

   ```
   @POST
   @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
   public Response post(@FormParam("foo") String foo
                        @FormParam("bar") String bar) {}
   ```
2. Use a `MultivaluedMap` to get all the params

   ```
   @POST
   @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
   public Response post(MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams) {
       String foo = formParams.getFirst("foo");
   }
   ```
3. Use `Form` to get all the params.

   ```
   @POST
   @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
   public Response post(Form form) {
       MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams = form.asMap();
       String foo = formParams.getFirst("foo");
   }
   ```
4. Use a `@BeanParam` along with individual `@FormParam`s to get all the individual params inside a bean.

   ```
   public class FormBean {
       @FormParam("foo")
       private String foo;
       @FormParam("bar")
       private String bar;
       // getters and setters
   }

   @POST
   @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
   public Response post(@BeanParam FormBean form) {
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks! MultivaluedMap was exactly what I needed. Note to anyone else reading this: having `@Context` on the MultivaluedMap caused it to be null. The value is only injected without the `@Context` annotation...

Comment: nice answer...saved my time and MultivaluedMap is what I was looking for which is without @context