# HttpServletRequest.getParameter always returns null

Tags: java, curl, jax-rs

I have the following code always returning null when calling getParameter()`

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/path")
public class MyResource {

    protected ResponseBuilder response;
    protected HttpServletRequest request;

    public MyResource(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
        this.response = Response.ok();
    }

    @POST
    public Response postTest() {
        JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject();

        String test = request.getParameter("test");

        log.debug(test);

        return response.entity(responseObj.toString()).build();
    }
}
```

I'm using this curl to trigger it:

```
curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: b7a3801f-b9d7-c7a1-004e-ac70b835d436" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'test=12345' 'http://localhost:8180/path'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where is `request` coming from? Is it an instance variable in whatever class that method is from?

Comment: Where/How are you mapping `/path` to the `postTest()` method?

Comment: I'm using `@Path("/path")` (updating code)

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612194/get-httpservletrequest-in-jax-rs-appfuse-application

Comment: Just use path params the REST style instead of fiddling with low level Servlet API.

Comment: Do you mean like that: `public Response postTest(@FormDataParam("test") String test) {...}` ? This worked :) Thanks

Comment: `@FormParam` not `@FormDataParam`. The latter is for multipart. [See also](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34258828/2587435)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

@Path("/path")
public class MyResource {

    protected ResponseBuilder response;
    protected HttpServletRequest request;

    public MyResource(@Context HttpServletRequest request) {
        this.request = request;
        this.response = Response.ok();
    }

    @POST
    public Response postTest(@FormParam("test") String test) {
        JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject();

        log.debug(test);

        return response.entity(responseObj.toString()).build();
    }
}
```