# Read POST form data with HttpServletRequest

Tags: java, servlets, http-post, jax-rs

It's been a couple of days where I am trying to read data that are POSTed from a Form, with the content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

According to [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST), datas that are sent to the server with POST request and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content-type are sent like this to the server:

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 13

say=Hi&to=Mom
```

I want to read the key and the value of `say` and `to` with the `HttpServletRequest`.

Here is my attempt :

```
@POST
@Path("/webhook/{psp_code}")    
public Response notifyPSP(@Context HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
  @PathParam("psp_code") String pspCode) {

    String payload = getRequestBody( httpServletRequest );
    Map<String, List<String>> formData = getFormData( httpServletRequest );

    log.info( "Payload {}", payload);  
    log.info( "Form Data {}", formData );
}

private String getRequestBody(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String content;

    try
    {
        ServletInputStream inputStream = request.getInputStream();
        content = IOUtils.toString( inputStream );
    }
    catch ( IOException e )
    {
        content = null;
    }
    return content;
}

private Map<String, List<String>> getFormData(HttpServletRequest request) {
    Map<String, String[]> parameterMap = request.getParameterMap();
    Map<String, List<String>> collect = parameterMap.entrySet().stream().collect( Collectors.toMap( entry -> entry.getKey(), entry -> Arrays.asList( entry.getValue() ) ) );
    return collect;
}
```

The output values are empty :

```
Payload
Form Data {}
```

Maybe I am missing somethings here but how can I read those values ?

Comment: Can you try logging the values of parameterMap. Because something is wrong with collect variable I hope.

Comment: Just for testing, I removed the collect and the raw values return by `getParameterMap` and still the same results

Comment: [Try these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34258916/2587435)